# ServiceBus Retry policy not working with QueueClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I want to limit no of retry in Azure ServiceBus queue receiver.

Sending messages using console application with **MaxRetryCount:3**

```
private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusConnection"];
        QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueName);
        queueClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
                minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                maxRetryCount: 3);

        string tradeData = File.ReadAllText("TradeSchemaDemo.json");
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(tradeData);
        await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
        await queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }
```

Another side I have Azure function to receive message,

```
public static void run([ServiceBusTrigger("TestQueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "servicebusconnection")]string myqueueitem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        retry++;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Retry attempt {retry}");
        throw new System.Exception("Human error");
        log.Info($"c# servicebus queue trigger function processed message: {myqueueitem}");
    }
```

Still, my function calling 10 times. Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `RetryPolicy` defines the amount of the retries for send operation, not on receiving side.

Receiver retry amount is defined by Queue property `Max Delivery Count`. You can set it on queue level with a tool like Service Bus Explorer or programmatically while creating the queue:

```cs
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queue = new QueueDescription(queueName);
queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 3;
if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
    namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, anyone want to see code

```
private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusConnection"];
        var nm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        var queue = new QueueDescription(QueueName);
        queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 3;
        if (!nm.QueueExists(QueueName))
            await nm.CreateQueueAsync(queue);

        QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueName);
        string tradeData = File.ReadAllText("TradeSchemaDemo.json");
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(tradeData);
        await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
        await queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You should edit my answer instead of creating a new one. I'll copy your code in case you don't have enough rep to do so.